# WordPress media uploader - upload tabs not hiding

Tags: customization, uploads, media, media-library, front-end

I'm in the process of adding a front-end post editor to one of my sites. In doing so, I need to prevent certain users from being able to upload media. I have things "kind of" working but there are a few problems.

1. Though the title for the Upload Media tab is hidden, the tab itself still displays and allows users to "drag and drop" for media upload. I want this entire tab content gone.
2. I've unset the Media Library Title, but it still shows up.

Here is the current code I'm using...

```
// Remove items from Media Uploader if current user has a Member role
function member_media_view_strings( $strings ) {
    $author_data = get_userdata( get_current_user_id() );
    $author_role = implode(', ', $author_data->roles);
    if ( $author_role == 'member' ) {
        unset( $string['uploadImagesTitle'] );
        unset( $strings['uploadFilesTitle'] );
        unset( $strings['createGalleryTitle'] );
    }

    return $strings;

}

add_filter( 'media_view_strings', 'member_media_view_strings', 99 );


// Remove items from Media Uploader if current user has a Member role
function member_media_view_tabs($tabs) {
    $author_data = get_userdata( get_current_user_id() );
    $author_role = implode(', ', $author_data->roles);
    if ( $author_role == 'member' ) {
        unset($tabs['gallery']);
        unset($tabs['type']);
    }

    return $tabs;

}

add_filter( 'media_upload_tabs', 'member_media_view_tabs', 99 );
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

-EDIT-

I've attached a screenshot of what the media uploader looks like now....it's weird.

[image: screenshot]